# Swing embed JavaFX panel, text field in panel on Japanese Language input, prediction text popup comes with different look and feel

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Please see the following code which resembles our use case:

```
public class SwingEmbedJavaFXExample extends JDialog {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SwingEmbedJavaFXExample().setJFX();
}

private void setJFX() {

    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    GridPane grid = createGridWithJavaFXLabelTextFieldAndAButton();


    getContentPane().add(jfxPanel);
    // initialize FX with JFXPanel which has scene get by gridPane
    //embedding jfxPanel to JDialog
    Platform.runLater(() -> initFX(jfxPanel, grid));
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private void initFX(JFXPanel jfxPanel, GridPane grid) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
}
@NotNull
private GridPane createGridWithJavaFXLabelTextFieldAndAButton() {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Label label = new Label("Label: ");
    grid.add(label, 0, 1);

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setId("PropertyNameTextfield");
    textField.setPromptText("promptText");

    grid.add(textField, 1, 1);
    grid.add(new Button("Hit me!"), 2, 1);
    return grid;
}
```

}

and the problem looks like this [IMAGE: Swing Embed Java Fx Problem with Japanese input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvEgY.png)

Problem is an extra text field with "ENTER" sign with prediction box and prediction box is displaying away from UI

**NOTE:** 
We can not use pure Javafx or pure Swing.

Comment: So - what exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: Which OS and which javafx version are you using? I remember that there was a similar bug related to accented characters: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185792

Comment: OS: Window 10 and Javafx version 11.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Platform.runLater what is happening is that it does not treat JavaFX Runnable differently and that's why it is not in sync with window-text-suggestion-service.

The solution is to use PlatformImpl.runAndWait which actually does not wait to run JavaFX Runnable to run and this causes a good synchronization with the window-text-suggestion service.

**Mantra**: With JavaFX application always use PlatformImpl.runAndWait instead of Platform.runLater.